# Building a suspending resource pool using Kotlin Coroutines

Tags: kotlin, concurrency, architecture, kotlin-coroutines

I'm exploring how to build a resource pool that suspends until a resource is available.
This pool can be anything, from slots to allow API calls to socket connections to image processors or in this sample code, integers which could be available service counters:

```
val pool = Pool(1, 2, 3)


repeat(100) {
    launch {
        pool.borrow {
            println(it)
            delay(1000)
        }
    }
}
```

The borrow function grabs one item from the resource pool and returns it once it's done.

What I've done so far is this:

```
class Pool(vararg resource: Int) {
    private val mutex = Mutex()
    private val list = mutableListOf(*resource.toTypedArray())
    private var available: CompletableDeferred<Boolean>? = null

    suspend fun add(value: Int) {
        mutex.withLock {
            list.add(value)
            available?.complete(true)
        }
    }

    suspend fun rem(): Int {
        mutex.withLock {
            if (list.size == 1) {
                available = CompletableDeferred()
            } else {
                available?.await()
            }
            return list.removeLast()
        }
    }

    suspend fun borrow(handler: suspend (Int) -> Unit) {
        val borrowed = rem()
        try {
            handler(borrowed)
        } finally {
            add(borrowed)
        }
    }
}
```

Both `add` and `rem`ove runs inside `mutex.withLock { ... }` to ensure we don't get a concurrent modification exception when two threads are trying to modify the same list.

Initially, available is null, so any `available?.await()` will be skipped due to the null check.
Once you remove the last item from the list (`list.size == 1`), available is set to a `CompletableDeferred` which means `available?.await()` will now suspend until `available?.complete(true)` is called.

Once more items are added, `available?.complete(true)` is called again which will stop `available?.await()` from suspending. If you try to remove an item, this code will deadlock, `available?.await()` will suspend which means the mutex never exits preventing `add` from being called again to allow the rem from unsuspending again.

If I move that `available?.await()` before the mutex, two threads will try to remove an item from a list that might only have one item in it and the second thread will hit a `List is empty`error.

What is the correct way to implement such a suspending resource pool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would be a lot easier to build using a Channel. You don't even need to make `add` suspending because you can use `trySend` from any thread safely when the Channel has an unlimited capacity.

I also suggest making `borrow` inline and removing `suspend` from its function parameter. This avoids a function wrapper allocation when you use it. Since it's inline, you'll still be able to call suspend functions in the lambda you pass to it even if it's not a suspend lambda.

```
class Pool<T>(vararg initialResources: T) {
    private val channel = Channel<T>(Channel.UNLIMITED)
    
    init {
        for (res in initialResources) {
            channel.trySend(res)
        }
    }

    fun add(value: T) {
       channel.trySend(value)
    }

    suspend fun rem(): T = channel.receive()

    suspend inline fun borrow(handler: (T) -> Unit) {
        val borrowed = rem()
        try {
            handler(borrowed)
        } finally {
            add(borrowed)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Channels seems like the sane way to implement this.
Is it possible to do this with flows too? I was running into a chicken-egg scenario with regular flows similar to the above deadlock where the producer and the consumer are suspending each other. ChannelFlows was not really acting like a channel and duplicating items depending on the buffer size.
To check if the items in the channel are active, I can probably just run a scheduler that cycles through all the channel items or even better, keep a second reference to each of the items in the channel so I can just forEach through all of them

Comment: There are so many different types of flows and use cases, I would have to know a lot more detail to really be able to discuss it.

Comment: if you were to replace a database connection pool with a flow, which one would you pick?

Comment: I haven’t worked with database connections. Having trouble visualizing how this would look as a flow. If you’re wanting a connection, you just want one, not an ongoing flow of them, right?

Comment: I was trying flow.take(1).collectLatest {  } which gives you exactly one. Maybe flows are just a poor fit for doing what a channel already does so brilliantly. For academic reasons, I did want to make it work though

Comment: To me, that looks awkward and doesn’t fit the intended use of Flows. It is analogous to returning lists of one item from all your functions, just to force the return value to always have to be unwrapped by using `.first()` on the list, and promising in the docs that it’s safe because the list will not be empty.

Comment: I've posted another solution using a Semaphore + Mutex which feels less like we're using a sledgehammer

Comment: Why do you consider this a sledgehammer? Channel is a capable and appropriate tool for the job, so why rebuild it using three other classes? The other advantage here is that you don't have to suspend and wait when returning items to the pool.

Answer (score 2):

There's another way to do this, using Semaphores

```
class ResourcePool<T>(vararg initialResources: T) {

    private val mutex = Mutex()
    private val semaphore = Semaphore(permits = initialResources.size)
    private val resources = initialResources.toMutableList()

    suspend operator fun invoke(handler: suspend (T) -> Unit) {
        semaphore.withPermit {
            val borrowed = mutex.withLock { resources.removeLast() }
            try {
                handler(borrowed)
            } finally {
                mutex.withLock { resources.add(borrowed) }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Running some benchmark against it:

```
 @ExperimentalTime
    fun main() = runBlocking {
        val r = ResourcePool(*(1L..5000L).toList().toTypedArray())
        val totals = mutableListOf<Duration>()
        repeat(500) {
            val l = mutableListOf<Job>()
            totals.add(measureTime {
                repeat(100_000) { l.add(launch { r {  } }) }
                l.forEach {
                    it.join()
                }
            })
            println(totals.last())
        }
        println("${totals.subList(totals.size / 2, totals.lastIndex).average()} (average)")
    }
```

> 42.284184ms (average)

and then we take the equivalent Channel implementation,

```
class ResourcePoolWithChannel<T>(vararg initialResources: T) {

    private val channel = Channel<T>(Channel.UNLIMITED)
    init {
        initialResources.forEach {
            channel.trySend(it)
        }
    }

    suspend operator fun invoke(handler: suspend (T) -> Unit) {
        val borrowed = channel.receive()
        try {
            handler(borrowed)
        } finally {
            channel.send(borrowed)
        }
    }
}
```

and run the same benchmarks against it:

```
@ExperimentalTime
fun main() = runBlocking {
    val r = ResourcePoolWithChannel(*(1L..5000L).toList().toTypedArray())
    val totals = mutableListOf<Duration>()
    repeat(500) {
        val l = mutableListOf<Job>()
        totals.add(measureTime {
            repeat(100_000) { l.add(launch { r {  } }) }
            l.forEach {
                it.join()
            }
        })
        println(totals.last())
    }
    println("${totals.subList(totals.size / 2, totals.lastIndex).average()} (average)")
}
```

> 56.524879ms (average)

The Semaphore + Mutex implementation is slightly faster than the Channel implementation.